# How to set data from database in recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-database

I want develop Android application and i use database for for save data! now i want show this datas from `SQLiteDatabase` into `RecyclerView`. 
How do this work? please send me sample or tutorial for this job.

**Attention :** I am amateur developer, please instead of give me negative point, please help me! i need your helps.

Comment: You should always search google for your questions before asking questions. This an example of a combination. But you should first do research on creating an SQLite db and then do research on creating a RecyclerView.   http://androidheight.blogspot.com/2015/11/sqlite-database-in-android-application.html

Comment: @EugeneH, thanks man <3